# How can I know which partition is EFI system partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, arch-linux, efi

I want to install ArchLinux from working dual-boot system. There's one step where I got stuck:

`# Mount the EFI System partition with:
   sh-4.3# mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/boot/efi`

I ran `fdisk -l` command and got its output. How can I know which of this partitions is exactly the EFI one? Is it the one with only `100mb` storage?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**None of them.** Either you don't have an EFI system, or Windows wasn't installed in EFI mode.

If you *had* an EFI system partition, it would always have the `ef` type code instead of the usual 07 or 82, and `lsblk -f` would show it as having a "vfat" filesystem.

Also, since Windows is rather picky about it, the disk would have a GPT disklabel (yours shows "dos" which means MBR), and fdisk wouldn't even show the type ids.

That first 100 MB partition is a "Microsoft System Reserved Partition"; while similar in purpose (even *meant to* mirror EFI layout), it is completely specific to the Windows boot process.

Comment: Hm, I have an UEFI-motherboard and thought this means that I have an EFI partition. I'm not strong in this stuff, really. Should I just create this partition or it's okay to continue without mounting EFI partition?

Comment: Most EFIs provide a feature called the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables the EFI to use BIOS-mode boot loaders and boot BIOS-mode OSes. Your system appears to be using this feature to boot Windows in BIOS mode. In some sense, you can think of your computer as having a BIOS, not an EFI; ***however,*** there is a danger: If you mistakenly install Linux in EFI mode, you'll have a mixed-mode installation, which will be difficult to dual-boot. Thus, you should be careful to install Linux *in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.*

Comment: @RodSmith, wow, you put everything in its place in my mind, thank you. I'm gonna find another way and this question, as I think, can be closed. Thanks, again!

Comment: Follow the Arch Linux instructions for installing in BIOS mode and you should be OK.